# How to pass the data from table view to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Im a newbie in Swift Language.. i want to pass the price from Table View controller to Payment View controller

Here my code for table view controller

```
import UIKit

class MainMenuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let labeltitle = ["ADLV Black Tee", "ASSC Black Hoodie", "CDG Play Gold Black Tee"]

    let labelprice = [("RM 250"), ("RM 305"), ("RM 418")]

    let myImage = [UIImage(named: "adlv1"), UIImage(named: "assc"), UIImage(named: "cdg1")]

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self


    }

//here got error 

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: (Any)?){
        var DestinationViewController : PaymentViewController = segue.destination as! PaymentViewController

        if let lText = labelprice.text {
            DestinationViewController.price = lText
        }


    }

    @IBAction func BuyNowbutton(_ sender: Any) {


    }


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return labeltitle.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MainMenuTableViewCell


        cell.label11?.text = labeltitle[indexPath.row]

        cell.label2?.text = labelprice[indexPath.row]

        cell.myImage.image = self.myImage[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }


}
```

Here my Payment view controller

```
import UIKit

class PaymentViewController: UIViewController {

    var items = [item]()
    var price : String = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var paymentdetails: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var cardnametextfield: UITextField!


    @IBOutlet weak var validthrutextfield: UITextField!


    @IBOutlet weak var cardnumbertextfield: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var cvcnumbertextfield: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var labelprice: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    labelprice.text = price


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func paybutton(_ sender: Any) {

        if cardnametextfield.text == "" {
            alertMessage(titleInput: "Error, Payment Unsuccessful!", messageInput: "Please Fill all the fields")
        } else if validthrutextfield.text == "" {
            alertMessage(titleInput: "Error, Payment Unsuccessful!", messageInput: "Please Fill all the fields")
        } else if cardnumbertextfield.text == "" {
            alertMessage(titleInput: "Error, Payment Unsuccessful!", messageInput: "Please Fill all the fields")
        } else if cardnumbertextfield.text == "" {
        alertMessage(titleInput: "Error, Payment Unsuccessful!", messageInput: "Please Fill all the fields")
        } else {
            alertMessage(titleInput: "Success!", messageInput: "Payment Successful!")

            self.transitionToHomePage()
        }
    }

    func alertMessage(titleInput: String, messageInput: String){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: titleInput, message: messageInput, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        let paybutton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(paybutton)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func transitionToHomePage(){
         let TabHomeViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constrants.Storyboard.TabHomeViewController) as? UITabBarController

        view.window?.rootViewController = TabHomeViewController
        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

}
```

Comment: please share the error ?

Comment: It shows value of type [String] has no member ‘texr’ @Sh_Khan

Comment: Please don't [repost questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61973795/how-to-pass-data-from-view-controller-to-other-view-controller). Instead edit the question and add more information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

**First** you should make a struct

```
struct Item {
  let title,price,imageName:String
}
```

instead of the 3 arrays make 1

```
var arr = [Item]()
```

and fill it

**Second**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: (Any)?){
    var des = segue.destination as! PaymentViewController 
    if let row = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {
        des.price = arr[row].price
    } 
}
```

Finally connect the segue from the tableView not from the cell and dragged it to the destination vc , then inside `didSelectRowAt` delegate method of table dp

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"SegueNameHere",sender:nil)
```

Comment: But the price is not pass, how to make it pass? @Sh_Khan